# @PreDestroy method not called in @Singleton on JBoss EAP 6.3.0

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6

In my JavaEE application, I have a `@Singleton` class containing some `@Scheduled` methods. Furthermore there are methods with `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` to set up and clean up the database. (For the sake of simplicity, I just have logging in the example, since that reproduces the problem.) The application has to run on a JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA server.

While the `@PostConstruct` method works fine, `@PreDestroy` is not called when I shutdown the server (neither when pressing the *stop the server* button in eclipse nor when using a `shutdown` command from jboss-cli). Here is some code, which reproduces the problem:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class TimerBean {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimerBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        log.info("PostConstruct called");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void preDestroy() {
        log.info("PreDestroy called");
    }
}
```

During startup of the server, the `@PostConstruct` message appears in the log. But when shutting down the server, no log message appears.

How can I make the server call the `@PreDestroy` method?

**EDIT**: Since the `@PreDestroy` method is not the appropriate location to clean up the database, this question is obsolete.

Comment: Have you tried it in a Wildfly 8 or EAP 7? Just to get shure it's not a bug in EAP 6.3.0.
Found this here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/291713 but seems to befixed in your version

Comment: have you tried this in Jboss 7 AS. i cant see any problem, this should work. but one thing, databse cleanup task should not be done in preDestroy, it is just to do some resource cleanup. but in your example it is just a log.info

Comment: There is also no `@PreDestroy` message when I deploy this to a Wildfly 8.

@hunter When PreDestroy is not the right place to do database cleanup, where else can I do it? (If there is a better solution than `@PreDestroy`, I don't care about why this doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the answer for your question, this is the answer for the question you raised in the last comment.
actually i can not think about a right place to do it.someone else might help you to figure it out.
but anyway @PostContruct and @PreDestory might not be a part of transaction, that's why it is not good to do DB operations in those methods,

But for your help i attach this which i took from a book (Mastering EJB 3.0),

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer is appreciated!

Comment: Thats why its not good idea to clean DB resources in @PreDestory method