# What happens to singleton when the app is redeployed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, weblogic, lifecycle

I have singleton in java ee with predestory method that closes initiated db connection.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ZpwLogowanie {
    private Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnectionConf();
    @PreDestroy
    private void close() {
        DbUtil.close(conn);
    }
}
```

What happens when whole application is redeployed (due to some development)?
Shouldnt be singleton destroyed?

I'm asking because from time to time when deploying application I have message:

```
weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolLimitSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool BAZA_XXX to allocate to applications
```

It sounds like previous connections were not deallocated.

Comment: ok. i see this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994279/predestroy-method-not-called-in-singleton-on-jboss-eap-6-3-0, so i change question a little bit. how should i handle closing db connection in this case?

Comment: I'm not asking if there are better approaches (like JPA, ...). I'm asking how should i handle this situation -> deallocation of resources in singleton.

Comment: ok. i will do it this way (that was my first approach). but generally can @Singleton be used in scenerio where there are some resources held (lets forget about db), when there is no guarantee for deallocation of this resources?